# Python 3 beautifulsoup html issue not finding game names

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

not sure what I am doing wrong but here is my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/score/metascore/year/pc/filtered?sort=desc&year_selected=2018"

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')   

game_names = html_soup.find_all("div", _class = "product_item product_title")


print(game_names)
```

I am try to find all the game name from this list and metascore but can't figure out the html for it, I think what I have should work but when I run it all I get is this:

```
[]
```

can someone explain?

I'm looking at the beautiuflsoup documentation but not sure where to look lol

Thank in advance for the help,

Comment: You have a typo use class_ not _class

Comment: I've always used `class_` not `_class` and don't know if the latter works! I suggest trying the former.